# how to rename button new in index active admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

how to rename button new text in index active admin rails?
example, i have button with value "New Book", how to change the text in button to "New Book Adventure"

i have code like this :

```
action_item :only => :index do
    config.clear_action_items!
    link_to "New Book Adventure" , "/admin/books/new" 
  end
```

but i get duplicate button in index page active admin?

Answer (score 20):

You just need to get the `config.clear_action_items!` line out of your `action_item` block

Just like this:

```
config.clear_action_items!

action_item only: :index do
  link_to 'New Book Adventure', '/admin/books/new'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `config.clear_action_items!` has a lot of side effects, therefore I'd recommend checking this instead:
https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html -> Renaming Action Items

Here is a summary:
Change the config/locales/[en].yml:

```
en:
  active_admin:
    resources:
      book: # Registered resource
        new_model: 'New Book Adventure' # new action item
        edit_model: 'Change Book Adventure' # edit action item
        delete_model: 'Delete Book Adventure' # delete action item
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35838045)